# Why do integrals work if you are summing things with zero area?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, riemann-integration

So I am a normal second year math student in who is currently taking probability theory. One of the things we learned is that if you have a continuous probability densities $f(x)$, then $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx = 1$. We also learned that $P(X = x) = 0$ as well. So it means that the probability of *something happening* is 100%, but the probability of *one specific thing* is 0%. This is pretty mind blowing for me, but it brought me back to Calculus 1 where we defined integrals as the limit of a Riemann Sum (which made sense from a proof standpoint).

However now I seem to have trouble fundamentally grasping how an infinite sum of objects with zero area could have a value. I know that we are taking the *limit*, not the actual, but does that mean that if we ever reached 0 it would instantly disconnect and drop off to zero?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What definition are you using for the probability in terms of the PDF?

Comment: I would rather think at it in a more down-to-earth way. If you have a continuous probability distribution, what you really measure is the probability that the outcome lies in a given interval, rather that the probability that the outcome attains an exact value. Hence an exact value is interpreted as a degenerate interval, and as such, probability degenerates to $0$.

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician we use the definition (I'm not looking at my notes so this is what I remember, pardon if its a little loose) that a PDF is a function that defines the probability of a random variable taking up a specific value

Comment: This is not an answer, but a pointer to some intuitive crutches. When dealing with a "continuous" probability distribution, one rarely cares about the probability of a single outcome. Instead, important events are represented by an interval of real numbers, or a higher dimensional shape such as a box or shape in a Cartesian coordinate system. So, one learns to think correctly about probability in two distinct ways: the discrete; and the continuous. In the discrete case, you add. In the continuous case, you integrate. Despite the theoretical connection, integration is not "infinite summation".

Comment: You want "density" in place of "distribution".

Comment: More abstractly, 'infinitely many things that are zero' is one of the canonical examples of an _indeterminate_ form; you can't say that (to use the standard mathematical shortcut for writing) "$\infty\cdot 0=0$" per se. (Consider $x\cdot \frac1x$ as $x\to\infty$, for instance).

Comment: Well no one is adding infinitely many things of size zero when defining an integral. Because frankly speaking one can't add infinitely many things.  An integral is the limit of a finite sum and nothing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are summing "infinitely many" things with zero area, so that infinity and zero "compensate" each other.

Things become clearer when you think of a decomposition of $f$ in contiguous rectangles, thus approximating $f$ in a piecewise constant manner. When you shrink the rectangle width, their number increases, for an approximately constant sum.